# Applying case Insensitive filter while using pymongo's update_many

Tags: python, python-3.6, pymongo-3.x

Can someone suggest how to update multiple documents while using regex in filter query of update_many?
Here is my query:

```
db['collection'].update_many({"col1":{ "$regex" : "NO" , "$options" : "i"}},{"$set":{"col2":"NO"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix that I used:

```
no_regex = ['no','No','NO']
db['collection'].update_many({"col1":{ "$in" : no_regex}},{"$set":{"col2":"NO"}})
```